# How to load JSON in Vue CLI without CORS error

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, electron, vue-cli

I have a Vue.js project wrapped in an Electron app. From one of my components (`src/components/MoviesTable.vue`), I'm making an axios call to a local JSON file (`public/data/multimedia.json`), like this:

```
axios.get('./data/multimedia.json').then(res => {
  this.movies = res.data.movies;
})
```

When I run `npm run serve` to serve the Vue app, I experience no issues. However, when I build the Electron app, I receive the error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '.../multimedia-index-app/dist/data/multimedia.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

I've tried using proxies to no avail. I know that similar questions about CORS have been asked on SO, which offer different solutions, but I'm a noob, and I need clearer instructions than the ones that I've come across.

Please let me know if you require more information. Any help in resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the JSON file should be bundled with the app, you don't need Axios, you can have Webpack load it:

```js
import movies from './data/multimedia.json';
```

And use it in the component:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      movies
    }
  }
}
```